# Creating class in CSS is correct by this method?

Tags: html, css

CSS

> .first{ color:red;                                 }

HTML

```
<class id=first> 
<p> some text </p> 
<p> some other text </p> 
</class>
```

Is it correct?

Comment: no you use the class attribute.

Comment: Use #first to select by id. Or use class=first in your html. But you should probably spend some time reading an introduction to CSS;

Comment: no.  try <p class="first">sometext</p><p class="first">someother text</p>

Comment: This is some of the most basic CSS things. Please follow some tutorials if you don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic HTML/CSS, and I cant really believe, that you did some research. Anyway, that's how it works:

CSS

```
#first {
    Color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="first"> 
    <p> some text </p> 
    <p> some other text </p> 
</div>
```

If you want to style classes you have to write .first, for ID's #first

EDIT: Where are my thoughts? The class Tag is not a valid HTML Tag, if you need a wrapper you can use the div Tag, for example. BTW: An Id has to be unique, if you want to style multiple div's red, use a class like this:

```
<div class="first"> 
    <p> some text </p> 
    <p> some other text </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm a student my teacher told me this , i searched about it but couldn't find anything about this so i post it here.

Comment: I guess your teacher is new to HTML/CSS as well ;) Here is a short explanation, how the selectors work: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

For that css you need

```
<p class='first'></p>
```

Comment: thsnks for reply , some one told me this method ,please see the question again.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see their reply.